# Selenium - input four digit numbers in input field changes five digit numbers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my code is like this

```py
item = ['tea', '5200']

driver.find_element_by_xpath(<path of the field>).send_keys(item[0])
driver.find_element_by_xpath(<path of the field>).send_keys(item[1])
```

when I run the code, the name of the item(item[0]) is completely work.
but the price of the item(item[1]) has some problem.

The default value of the price field is 0 and it changes into 05200 after I run the code.

I tried both int and str type and both has same problems.

Comment: what happens in the application when you type the same number manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the input box first.

Try this:

```py
item = ['tea', '5200']

driver.find_element_by_xpath(<path of the field>).send_keys(item[0])
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(<path of the field>)
element1.clear()
element1.send_keys(item[1])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad that it worked, good luck with your poject!